# Google Maps Flutter plugin for IOS: Undefined symbol

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, cocoapods

I am testing a flutter app for IOS. I am using a Macincloud M2 Mac with arm64 architecture.I am using Cocoapods.

When I try to run it I get the error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FLTGoogleMapsPlugin

I cleaned my project and reinstalled my dependencies

I updated the pod repository

Specified the version of Google Maps to my Podfile as per the documentation.

`target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

pod 'GoogleMaps', '8.4.0'

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(**FILE**))
end`

I read that some folks have issues with non arm64 architecture and have to exclude it on xcode but I dont have that issue since I am using an M2.

I was expecting to be able to run the app on the simulator